# How do I route by domain / subdomain in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, dns, subdomain

I looked at subdomain-fu and it looks pretty easy to route all non-www and non-'' subdomain requests to a single controller.

But I also, need to send all external domains that are CNAME'd to my domain to the same controller.  I have done a lot of searching and I can't find anything.

Summarized, if it is a subdomain on my domain it goes to Catchall controller, if it is any other domain than my domain, it goes to the same Catchall controller.

I am going nuts on this, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should check out the [request_routing](http://agilewebdevelopment.com/plugins/request_routing) plugin.  It allows you to easily route request by:   subdomain, domain, method, port, remote_ip, content_type, protocol, etc.