# Rails 3 Different Routes File Depending on Subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I building a Rails 3 app that has a couple of different subdomains which need to have their own set of routes specific to that subdomain. How do I set this up? I know that I can pass something like :constraints { :subdomain => "api" } to an individual route but I don't want to have to do this for each resource/route in my application.

Is there a way to either load a different routes file depending on my subdomain or group subdomain routes into a block?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283755/how-do-i-route-by-domain-subdomain-in-rails  The question is a bit more specific but the answer is the same.  You might also try the subdomain-fu gem.

Answer (score 1):

I'd simply set constraints on the routes as described [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#request-based-constraints).